# Cloud Functions for Firebase ( No Log Messages)

Tags: android, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

This is my first time using Cloud Functions for Firebase and Node.js, so

I have no idea why I can't see any logs on my Firebase console.

At least, I've successfully deployed the function below

```
'use strict';

 const functions = require('firebase-functions');

 //import admin module
 const admin = require('firebase-admin');
 admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);


 /* Listens for new messages added to events and sends a notification to 
 subscribed users */
 exports.pushNotification = 
  functions.database.ref('/events/{pushId}').onWrite( event => {

  console.log('Push notification event triggered');
  /* Grab the current value of what was written to the Realtime Database 
   */
    var valueObject = event.data.val();

     /* Create a notification and data payload. They contain the     
     notification information, and message to be sent respectively */ 
   const payload = {

     data: {
        eventType: valueObject.eventType,
        receiver: valueObject.receiver,
        requester: valueObject.requester
      }
     };

     /* Create an options object that contains the time to live for the 
      notification and the priority. */
      const options = {
          priority: "high",
          timeToLive: 60 * 60 * 24 //24 hours
      };

      return admin.messaging().sendToTopic(valueObject.receiver, payload, 
       options).then(function (response) {

            console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log("Error sending message:", error);
        });
       });
```

However, I couldn't see any log messages on Firebase Console even if I write some data to my 'events' database.
Does it mean this function wasn't triggered at all?

I would really appreciate if someone could suggest the cause of this issue.

Comment: Function invocations are logged in the Cloud Functions for Firebase console by default, even if you don't have any `console.log()` statements in your code. Is that not happening for you?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen No, I can't see any logs, but It says there are 15 executions right now. I get 2 additional executions whenever I deploy the function again.

Comment: Can you find any issue with my code regarding this problem?

Comment: Hmm... I don't know what's going on there. I always see logging in https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/functions/logs?search=&severity=DEBUG

Answer (score 0):

If you've set up your application correctly in the console, then there's no reason why logging would not happen if the function is fired.

That leaves you with the possibility that the function is not being fired up. A possible reason for that is that the data is not being written at the path provided in your function.

So, are you adding a value to `/events` such as `'true'` or `'ABC'`, or are you adding a child to it such as `{'ABC' = true}`?
In the case of `.ref(/events/{pushId})`, the function will be called in the latter case and not the former.

Comment: I added a child as the latter case. It's really weird because my console shows that the number of executions increases whenever I add a child to the database. Is it possible for functions to be executed without any log messages?

Comment: Well, no, a default log is created each time a function is fired up. Your situation is quite peculiar! Let me go through your code in a more thorough manner and do some more research. I'll make an edit if I have an updated answer.